# 《Компенсация ранних(,) и потому глобальных(,) разочарований.》

Tags: пунктуация

> Также обращается внимание на то, что нарциссическая патология — это не
> сохранившееся до взрослого возраста нормальное детское чувство
> собственной грандиозности, а скорее компенсация ранних, и потому
> глобальных разочарований во взаимоотношениях.

В [статье](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) перед "и потому" запятая стоит. Если стоит правильно, как это объяснить? После "глобальных" в таком случае запятая не нужна ли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*...компенсация **ранних и потому глобальных** разочарований во взаимоотношениях.*

Запятая не нужна, это тема **дифференцирующих (уточняющих) слов для однородных (сближенных по значению) определений.** В качестве **дифференцирующих элементов** могут выступать: подчинительные и присоединительные союзы, наречия, частицы, модальные и вводные слова. В данном случае таким элементом является сочетание **"и поэтому".**

Оснований **для обособления** (выделения) второго определения тоже нет, к тому же при обособлении нужны две запятые.

Розенталь: § 12. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные неповторяющимися союзами, пункт 5 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100
*Поставлена трудная, зато интересная задача; Слышалась жалобная, если не униженная просьба пощадить его самолюбие; В кинофильме рассказывается о первой, пусть неразделённой любви; Получены важные, хотя и не итоговые сведения;*

Comment: К сожалению, не могу. Jim Korbett человек особенный. Он сам пишет себе учебники, в которых  интонации вообще нет. Не стоит ему мешать))